# G-test in R and Python (Two Sample Test of Proportions)

Tags: python, r, statistical-test

I am conducting the G test in both R and Python and I am getting different results, the results I am getting in Python being wrong. Somehow I am misapplying the formula.

The data are:

```
prfs
Sex F   M
Pref        
B   29  17
A   2   12
```

The R Code is :

```
library(RVAideMemoire)
G.test(prfs)
G-test

data:  prfs
G = 11.025, df = 1, p-value = 0.0008989
```

The Python code is :

```
stats.power_divergence(prfs, lambda_ = 'log-likelihood')
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=array([28.14366538,  0.86639163]), pvalue=array([1.12635722e-07, 3.51956200e-01]))

stats.power_divergence(prfs, lambda_ = 'log-likelihood', axis = None, ddof = 2)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=29.07673602201342, pvalue=6.956736686069527e-08)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its an old question but following answer may help:

```
obs = np.array([[29,17], [2,12]])
# G test with scipy: 
from scipy.stats import * 
g, p, dof, expctd = chi2_contingency(obs, lambda_="log-likelihood")
print("G={}; df={}; P={}".format(g, dof, p))
```

Output:

```
G=8.859368223179882; df=1; P=0.0029158847773319975
```

The values are similar to those obtained by R method.

Reference for above method is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html#r223).